# How to manipulate stdout?

Tags: c++

For example, when using GitHub CLI, they prompt you like so:

```
Do something? (Y/n)
```

and if you were to input `n` and press 'Enter', then that output would change to:

```
Do something? No
'Next line's content'
```

I would like to do something similar in my program.

In my use case, it would look like:

```
Row 1: 1 2 3
Row 2: 4 5 6
Row 3: 7 8 9
Row 4:
```

where the user inputs the integers, presses 'Enter', and is now on `Row 4:` .

Upon the user pressing 'Enter', I would like it to transform into:

```
Row 1: 1 2 3
Row 2: 4 5 6
Row 3: 7 8 9
Row 4: N/A
```

or, preferably:

```
Row 1: 1 2 3
Row 2: 4 5 6
Row 3: 7 8 9
```

but I am not sure how to do this, since the user hitting 'Enter' would put `std::out` at the new line, and if I were to print out `N/A`, it would look like:

```
Row 1: 1 2 3
Row 2: 4 5 6
Row 3: 7 8 9
Row 4:
N/A
```

Comment: [`ncurses`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) is a popular library for text-based UIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminal applications do this by sending [special control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to the terminal (this is an extremely old school API!). Libraries like `ncurses` and external tools like `tput` can make the arcane incantations for you, but it's not too hard to do yourself.

In this case, once the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you want to move the cursor back up to the start of the previous line, clear the rest of the line, and write what you want instead.

```
#define ESC_PREV_LINE "\e[F"
#define ESC_CLEAR_TO_END "\e[K"

std::cerr << "Row 4: " << std::flush; // traditionally, interactive prompts appear on stderr! this makes it easy to separate the "real" output of a program from the interactive part to e.g. save in a file
// read input...
if(need_to_rewrite_input) {
  std::cerr << ESC_PREV_LINE ESC_CLEAR_TO_END "Row 4: 7 8 9\n";
}
```

You may want to check at the start of the program that `cerr` actually refers to a terminal, and either use a fallback behavior or just die if it's not.

Comment: When I run your code, like so: ```     int i;
    std::cerr << "Row 4: " << std::flush;
    std:: cin >> i;
    if(true) {
      std::cerr << ESC_PREV_LINE ESC_CLEAR_TO_END "Row 4: 7 8 9\n";
    }``` I get : `Row 4: 3
[F[KRow 4: 7 8 9`, where [F and [K appear in the stream, and the effect you described is not achieved (the output inside the if statement appears on the next line).

Comment: Odd, works fine for me (Windows Terminal). What terminal application are you using?

Comment: I was using Xcode @htnw . It works in my terminal. Thank you. Could you please tell me what `std::flush` is doing here? I read up on it, but it doesn't yet intuitively make sense to me.

Comment: Also, do you know how I could make it work in Xcode? It would be really inconvenient to have to do my testing outside the platform I'm developing on.

Comment: @user18348324 The standard streams are typically line-buffered. If you write an incomplete line to any of them, it will not actually be sent ("flushed") without the newline. An explicit `std::flush` can flush a stream anyway. `std::cout` and `std::cin` are `tie`d together, so that any read from `cin` first flushes `cout`. I wrote the `flush` here as `cin` is not tied to `cerr` (I believe), so reading `cin` may not flush `cerr`, so you might end up waiting on a read while the prompt is stuck in the buffer. But it seems to work for me without, so maybe I should figure out what's happening...

Comment: @user18348324 I have no idea how to make Xcode handle escape codes. Perhaps ask a new question?

Comment: That all made sense @htnw, until you began to explain the "tying together", what does that mean? They use the same buffer?

Comment: `#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "Hello, I am not flushed.";
    
    usleep(100000000);
    
    cout << "Hello, I am being flushed." << flush;
}` This code prints the first string literal immediately, which contradicts what you're saying.

Comment: @user18348324 The specific behavior is not portable. E.g. I just compiled your code on a Linux system and now no output appears immediately. Maybe Apple just decided to be forgiving to programmers (at the expense of speed). The bottom line is: if it's not flushed, it may nor may not appear. If you need something to appear, flush. But this is going off on a tangent...

Comment: As for your escape sequences @HTNW, I believe `\033[A` and `\33[2K` may be more portable. Do you know where I could find a table of them all?

Comment: The Wikipedia page I linked is pretty comprehensive?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a library like ncurses.   That is particularly relevant if, for example, you want to overwrite output on multiple lines preceding the cursor.

If you're looking for something more basic (as in, only affect output on the last line, and without much error checking, and without relying on escape codes that are often device specific) you can do something like

```
const std::string yesno = "(Y/n)"
char input;
std::cout << "Do something? " << yesno << " ";
std::cin >> input;
if (std::toupper(input) == 'Y')
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < yesno.length() + 2; ++i)
       std::cout << "\b \b";
    std::cout << 'Y';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
// code that produces next line of output
```

The loop backs up an overwrites characters on the last line, one at a time.  The magic number `2` in the loop comes from the need to overwrite the space character and the single character entered by the user.

The downside of the above is that it ASSUMES the user enters exactly one character before hitting the enter key.   There is no way to prevent the user doing something different (e.g. a user may happily enter YYYY before hitting the enter key).

To deal with that, one can do

If you want to relax that assumption the following is possible

```
const std::string yesno = "(Y/n)"
std::string input;
std::cout << "Do something? " << yesno << " ";
std::getline(std::cin, input);
if (input.length() > 0 && std::toupper(input[0]) == 'Y')
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < yesno.length() + input.length() + 1; ++i)
       std::cout << "\b \b";
    std::cout << 'Y';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
// code that produces next line of output
```

This will cope with the user entering YNYN before the enter key, by checking only the first character entered, and ignoring (and overwriting) the rest.

Both of the above do assume that outputting a space character will overwrite the character at the cursor position).   But default settings of most modern terminals or consoles (hardware device or emulator in a windowing system) are consistent with that assumption.    There are some old devices (largely obsolete, and now rarely seen outside historical displays or museums) for which that assumption is not true  [and ncurses will often not detect, let alone properly handle, such devices either].

The other assumption made is that the terminal width exceeds the length of user input.  So, if the terminal/window width is 80 characters, it is assumed the user will not enter 80 or more characters before hitting the enter key.

Comment: I ran both your code in my terminal, and it doesn't really appear to be doing anything at all. May I ask what the purpose of `std::tolower(input) == 'Y'` is when the result on the LHS will always be lowercase?

Comment: @user18348324  Typo - I'll fix in a moment.